# How a git repo local directory can be extracted when a hook is executed?

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

Basically as it says that is. Imagine the following hook code:

```
@echo on
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo %CD%         :: Try to print the current dir
echo %GIT_DIR%    :: Try to print the Git dir
echo.
echo.
ping 127.0.0.1 -t :: Loop on localhost, because timeout will break the hook
```

As it runs it does not print anything, I've put @echo on just for that..

Any Ideas. Tanks !

Answer (score 0):

A pre-commit hook will be executed (even on Windows) in a shell session (not a Windows CMD one)

Try and see if a pre-commit script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo test
```

does display something when you commit.

Comment: I am on windows, and I fixed my pb relocated into outout file ;)
I made a custom on Using Lua scrpt